# Mechanize: what kind of object return submit method?

Tags: python, forms, mechanize

My problem is that I have a form to submit, but after the submit this one redirect the user to a second page (which address is quite random) and ask for a confirmation. This second page consist of a form with only two button: Cancel and Continue. I would like to automatically submit this second form after the completion of the first one...So I ask If would be possible to exploit the object returned by the first submit. Unfortunately  the documenation is very poor...
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you use mechanize to submit the first page, it creates a response that you can capture with

```
resp=br.submit()
```

br then opens the second page so instead of actually capturing the response, you can actually just click/submit continue depending on the input type.  Good luck!